# SQL request with GROUP BY and SUM in Eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I just want make a simple sql request in my laravel application.

I'm not very comfortable with Eloquent aha.

This is the SQL request I want to make with eloquent :

```
select user_id, project_id, sum(hours)
FROM time_entries
WHERE spent_on BETWEEN '2018-04-10' AND '2018-12-10'
GROUP BY user_id, project_id
```

I've been trying something like :

```
TimeEntries::whereBetween('spent_on', [($request->input('debut')), ($request->input('fin'))])->groupBy('user_id')->sum('hours');
```

(but you can see it's hopeless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [selectRaw()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-methods).

```
TimeEntries::whereBetween('spent_on', [($request->input('debut')), ($request->input('fin'))])->groupBy(['user_id', 'project_id'])->selectRaw('user_id , project_id, sum(hours) as sum')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `selectRaw` function of Eloquent,
 like this:

```php
TimeEntries::selectRaw('user_id, project_id, sum(hours)')
    ->whereBetween(
        'spent_on',
        [ ($request->input('debut')), ($request->input('fin')) ]
    )
    ->groupBy('user_id', 'project_id');
```

But be aware that not to binding variables in the `selectRaw` string parameter, it might cause SQL injection problem since it by-pass the escaping check

Answer (score 0):

Below query will work:

```
$query = TimeEntries::query();
$query->selectRaw('user_id', 'project_id', sum(hours))
->whereRaw("spent_on >= '2018-04-10' and spent_on <= '2018-12-10'")
->groupBy('user_id')
->groupBy('project_id');

$result = $query->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

> Model->select(DB::raw('user_id, project_id,
>   SUM(hours)')->whereBetween...